# Are there any drawbacks to relying on a synthesized memberwise initializer in a container view?

Tags: swiftui

Obviously synthesized memberwise initializers make code less cluttered and therefore easier to read, but is there a risk of a performance hit when relying on them in a container view?

A container view could be written thus:

```
struct ContainerCustomInitView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    
    let content: Content
    
    init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.orange)
            content
        }
    }
}
```

In this example, a custom initializer calls the passed-in closure and stores its result in a property. This should ensure that the closure is only called once per instance of the container.

The equivalent implementation relying on a synthesized memberwise initializer would look like this:

```
struct ContainerSynthesizedMemberwiseInitView<Content>: View where Content: View {
    
    @ViewBuilder
    let content: () -> Content
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.orange)
            content()
        }
    }
}
```

Here, there is no choice but to call the closure within the body property. Is there any danger that the code defining the body property’s value could be called multiple times and therefore content() would be called a likewise number times? I assume that it can’t and the testing I’ve done seems confirm this assumption.

But before I do this sort of thing all over the place, (and potentially later on start scratching my head because my app is running at a snail’s pace), can somebody with a more authoritative knowledge advise me on this concern please?

Comment: I wish I could find the source, but I can't so this won't be too reliable, but: this came up in a WWDC SwiftUI lab. The engineer suggested that your first option could be slightly better, since it doesn't compute every time, but I *believe* didn't seem overly concerned either way.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to search it out.

Comment: @Steredain what you're calling "implicit" is a synthesized memberwise initializer. I disagree with the above assessment that the question is less valuable without knowing the exact term, as you've clearly demonstrated with concise code examples what you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks @jnpdx for for the jargon busting. :)